# Why is my boost converter output lower than expected?

Tags: ltspice, inductor, buck-boost

I have simulated this boost converter circuit in LTspice:

[image]

[image]

[image]

According to [this calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html), I should be getting 140V output.

[image]

My output is only 115V. I suspect it's something to do with the MOSFET, but I am not sure what to look for.

Comment: If you need a 30 times step-up ratio, a straight boost is probably not your best choice. What’s your output current? If 1400 ohm load, that 16 W will be a challenge. Not impossible though. I would recommend a flyback or push-pull instead.

Comment: Driver pulse voltage is too low. You should use 12 V ... unless IRF640ns is a "logic" device.

Comment: The datasheet for the obsolete IRF640 shows that it turns on well when its gate-source voltage is 10V. Most Mosfets with the preface IRL turn on well when the gate-source voltage is 5V (called logic level).

Comment: IRF740 - 400V (logic level)  should be used. NB Duty=0.97 is "necessary" ( a bit too high ?).

Comment: @winny The output current is 100mA.  Yeah, it's looking like it's going to be really tight trying to get this working with just a boost.

Comment: Have you tried simulating a push-pull or just two stage boost? Your peak to average ratio of both current and voltage stress on your MOSFET and diode will basically skyrocket the higher you go in step up ratio.

Comment: I'll second what @winny wrote about the boost ratio.  A boost converter shouldn't have a boost ration greater than 6x.  If a greater ratio is needed, then use a flyback converter.  Or several boost converters one after another.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I would do the flyback converter, but there doesn't seem to be an off the shelf transformer with a 1:30 ratio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The likely problem here is that the [MBRS1100](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/VISH/VISH-S-A0009498371/VISH-S-A0009498371-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0) diode you have used is only rated for a reverse voltage of 100 volts and you are expecting it to block 135 volts (output voltage minus input voltage). OK, that doesn't mean the simulator is necessarily modelling all the diode's characteristics but, in my opinion, most sims will show a problem if the maximum reverse voltage is exceeded.

I don't think that the [IRF640 MOSFET](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91036/sihf640.pdf) will be all that effective/efficient with a gate voltage drive of only 5 volts either. For instance, in your example linked example, the MOSFET has to handle a peak current of 3.3 amps and a minimum current of 2.3 amps: -

[image]

Hence, with a gate drive of only 5 volts, it's barely able to perform at all according to the typical characteristics in the data sheet.

Maybe try and find a 200 volt logic level MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense. I mistakenly was only looking at the threshold voltage and not the RDS

Comment: @Movieboy thanks for using my website calculator.

Answer (score 4):

If not the diode, then:

- you've chosen a FET that doesn't even *mention* it's \$\mathrm{R_{DS(on)}}\$ figure at \$\mathrm{V_{GS}} = 5 \mathrm V\$, but you're driving it at 5V (you should drive it at 10V at least, it's probably intended for 12V.
- The features say it's optimized for operation below a switching speed of 100kHz.  But this is really about pulse widths based on  sane duty cycles, by whatever definition of "sane" Infineon wants to use.  They're *probably* thinking 10% to 90%.  Your step-up ratio demands a duty cycle very close to 100%, which is going to cause you problems.

It's a general rule of thumb that you don't want a straight boost or buck converter with a ratio greater than 10:1.  In your case you could either break this into two converters, each with a step-up ratio between 5:1 or 6:1, or you could see if you could find a suitable flyback transformer and use that topology.

Since 140V is getting into power line-ish voltages, and 16W is a common off-line converter power level, there's a good chance that there's some off the shelf flyback transformer that'll work.  It may be twice the size of one that's optimized exactly for your application, but if you're working with low volumes you need to take what you can get and be happy with it.